# SOAP PHP script returns a blank screen

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a really simple PHP script that makes a SOAP request to webservicex  geoipservice

The WSDL is http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

The PHP script is as follows:

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';

 $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1)); 
 $response = $client->GetGeoIP('IPAddress','198.252.206.16');

var_dump($response);
print_r(array_values($response));
```

Yet it returns a blank screen.

The SOAP UI test is shown here and works fine: [SOAP UI Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6beVp.png)

I am sure the method is correct, I really can't see what's wrong. Can you help?

Comment: Anything in your php error log ? The location is normally defined by your php.ini or apache vhost

Comment: Hi, i turned on tracing so you can see in the browser. The link is http://amarria.co.uk/test.php

Comment: Have you tried either:
$response = $client->GetGeoIP('IPAddress' => '198.252.206.16');
or
$response = $client->GetGeoIP('198.252.206.16');

Comment: Does a blank screen mean that `var_dump($response)` didn't output anything at all, or that you never reached this point?

Comment: Just tried them, no luck. I also tried using the second format in a variable but got the same error.@GreensterRox

Comment: @andrel Please check out the link in the second comment. I have added tracing to show that the call is succeeding but something has gone wrong.

Comment: The error seems to originate from the server, cause by an unexpected null-value. Try to log the message/response and compare it to the request SoapUI creates.

Comment: thanks @andrei that gives me a bit more information. From the response it looks like the IPAddress  is not being sent or is not registered

Comment: @andrei with your debugging techniques I was able to solve. GreensterRox I used the second format. Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator to ensure the way to send the request. Currently I think the data is not well defined as the `GetGeoIP` awaits to have an object or an array and you're giving it 2 parameters instead of one.

You should try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.

Answer (score 0):

It shows a blank page because the soap client throws an exception and you probably have `display_errors` PHP setting to `0` or some production values for `error_reporting`.

Now, for the "*why is it throwing an exception ?*" part:

You're not sending the proper values for the request. You can inspect you're soap request using `__getLastRequest` method of `SoapClient`.
Looking in the wsdl, the `GetGeoIP` soap call needs an parameter of type `GetGeoIP` which in turn contains a node name IPAddress. You need to build these using `SoapVar` or create a class (or use a wsdl to php generator).

Here's your working example:

```php
$wsdl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';
// you can get the NS from the wsdl
$wsdlNS = "http://www.webservicex.net/";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
$IPAddress = new SoapVar('198.252.206.16', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'IPAddress', $wsdlNS);
$GetGeoIP = new SoapVar(['IPAddress' => $IPAddress], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'GetGeoIP', null, 'GetGeoIP', $wsdlNS);
$response = $client->GetGeoIP($GetGeoIP);

var_dump($response);
```